# How to use case statements in mysql using joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on product and category and product discount thing. I have done for a product discount. But the problem in while calculating category_discount. Here is my code :

```
SELECT products.id, products.product_name, products.product_price, products.product_discount, categories.category_discount,
(CASE WHEN products.product_discount = 0  THEN products.product_price
      WHEN products.product_discount != 0 THEN products.product_price - ( products.product_price *  products.product_discount)/100
      WHEN categories.category_discount !=0 THEN products.product_price - ( products.product_price *  categories.category_discount)/100
   END) AS amount
 FROM products
 join 
categories
on products.category_id = categories.id
```

See my result below it's not calculating category_discount for the first row:-
[image]

Comment: No images please. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Case _expression_ (since it returns a value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then When-statements are evaluated in order, until one is fulfilled.
In first row, the first When-clause is fulfilled, so there is no discount. Try below instead:

```
 WHEN products.product_discount = 0  AND categories.category_discount = 0   THEN products.product_price
```

Or even reorder like this:

```
 SELECT products.id, products.product_name, products.product_price, products.product_discount, categories.category_discount,
 (CASE WHEN products.product_discount != 0 THEN products.product_price - ( products.product_price *  products.product_discount)/100
  WHEN categories.category_discount !=0 THEN products.product_price - ( products.product_price *  categories.category_discount)/100
    ELSE products.product_price
 END) AS amount
 ...
```

Comment: yeah sure its shwoing you can accept answer in 10 min